# Reloading from checkpoing during AWS Sagemaker Training

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker is a great tool to train your models, and we save some money by using AWS spot instances. However, training jobs sometimes get stopped in the middle. We are using some mechanisms to continue from the latest checkpoint after a restart. See also the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html).

Still, how do you efficiently test such a mechanism? Can you trigger it yourself? Otherwise you have to wait until the spot instance actually ís restarted.

Also, are you expected to use the linked `checkpoint_s3_uri` argument or the `model_dir` for this? E.g. the `TensorFlow` estimator [docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/sagemaker.tensorflow.html#tensorflow-estimator) seem to suggest something `model_dir`for checkpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't manually terminate a sagemaker instance, run an Amazon SageMaker Managed Spot training for a small number of epochs, Amazon SageMaker would have backed up your checkpoint files to S3. Check that checkpoints are there. Now run a second training run, but this time provide the first jobs’ checkpoint location to `checkpoint_s3_uri`. Reference is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-guide-to-using-spot-instances-with-amazon-sagemaker-b9cfb3a44a68), this also answer your second question.

Comment: Thanks. So model_dir is only for when your finished? Bit confusing, but well :)

Comment: Do you also know how to do this for hyper parameter jobs? Because in this scenario they are all sharing the same checkpoint folder...

Comment: `model_dir` is used to normally store checkpoints and model artifacts, everything that is inside this folder at the end of the training job is compressed and stored to `s3`. I agree this name is not the best.. :)
Reguarding hyper parameters jobs I never dealt with it, so cannot help..

Comment: For future readers: HPs are also dealt with in this way, since sagemaker nicely appends the runid to `checkpoint_s3_uri`.